# Finding Large Pseudoprimes with a Computer

Tags: prime-numbers, python, pseudoprimes

I'm reading the book [Prime and Programming](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Primes_and_Programming.html?id=lnbEOBIlZYUC&redir_esc=y&hl=en) and I'm stuck on one of the computer exercises.

I'm checking for Fermat Pseudoprimes and I've written a program that works for reasonably small numbers, e.g. $\le  10^6$. It just brute-force checks that $b^{n-1} \equiv 1\bmod n$.

Now I'm asked to find the smallest prime or base 2 pseudoprime greater that $10^{15}$.

Python is unable to calculate $2^{10^{15}-1} \bmod 10^{15}$, never mind check case after case.

I must be missing a piece of Maths that will simplify the calculation massively.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you calculating $2^{10^{15} - 1} \pmod{10^{15}}$? I'm not having any problems with Python attempting that.

Comment: > 2 * * ( ( 10 * * 15 ) -1 ) % 10 * * 15

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Use `pow(2, 10**15 - 1, 10**15)` instead.

Comment: Why is that faster?

Comment: It optimises the exponentiation by using the fact that intermediates can be reduced mod $10^{15}$. I don't know the actual implementation, but a common method is to use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Further_applications).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate powers modulo n you can use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) together with [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic); the Python built-in function pow does that (not math.pow, which accepts only 2 parameters).

pow (x, y, n) calculates (x**y) % n.

The paper [New Implementations of Tabulating Strong Pseudoprimes and Liars, Wuyang Liu, Illinois Wesleyan University](https://digitalcommons.iwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=math_honproj) describes an algorithm that calculates (strong) Fermat Pseudoprimes up to a given bound. But for a range of big numbers as $n > 10^{15}$ that still requires much time.

The first 16-digit strong pseudoprime base 2 is 1000003918690669 ([OEIS-A062568](https://oeis.org/A062568)).

If you look for some, but not necessarily the next, pseudoprime you can calculate candidates ($q$) with the following formula in nested loops, e. g. k running from 1 to 99, m from k+1 to 100 and x such that $q > 10^{15}$ and then test if $q$ is a strong pseudoprime. Those number are more often strong pseudoprime than odd nunbers in general.

$\ q = (2\cdot k \cdot x + 1) \cdot (2 \cdot m \cdot x + 1)\ $ with

$\quad x \in \mathbb N$,

$\quad \gcd(k, m) = 1\ $ and

$\quad 0 < k \ll q,\ 0 < m \ll q\ $